# How do I change the character displayed in the 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating this console game in java where the player will be prompted to enter the dimension of the board and will be asked to move within the board using WASD keys which means up, left, down and right respectively. I have already displayed the board and the initial position of the player with the symbol `@`. I'm having a hard time changing the symbol every time I want the player to move in the board. Here's my code

```
public class Bord {
    public int n;
    public int i, j, a, b, c;
    public char move;
    public char board[][] = new char[n][n];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Bord() {
        System.out.println("\n\t************");
        System.out.println("\n\tThe Ant Game\n");
        System.out.println("\t************");
        System.out.println("\nInstructions: \nWelcome to Ant Game. You are the ant (@). \nUse 'w', 'a', 's', or 'd' to move");
        System.out.print("up, left, down or right consecutively. \nThere will be traps or rewards hidden \nin each tile (*) so be careful. Good luck!");
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter board dimension: ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        char board[][] = new char[n][n];

        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
                board[i][j] = '*'; 
        }             

        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        board[i][j] = '@';

        for(a=0; a<n; a++){
            System.out.print("\t");
            for(b=0; b<n; b++){
                System.out.print(board[a][b]);
                for(c=0; c<n; c++)
                    System.out.print("");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
             System.out.println();


        System.out.print("Press WASD for movement: ");
        move = in.next().charAt(0);


        switch (move)
        {
            //Move Up   
            case 'w':{
                if(i==0&&j==0){
                    System.out.println("End of boundary.");
                    System.out.print("Move again: ");
                    move = in.next().charAt(0);
                }
                else{
                    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
                            board[i][j] = '*'; 
                }             

                    i = 0;
                    j = 0;
                    board[i-1][j] = '@';

                    display();

                System.out.print("Move again: ");
                move = in.next().charAt(0);
                }
            break;    
            }

            //Move Left
            case 'a':
                System.out.println("End of boundary.");
                System.out.print("Move again: ");
                move = in.next().charAt(0);
             break;   

             //Move Right
            case 'd':{
                board[i][j+1] = '@';

                i = 0;
                j = 0;
                board[i][j] = '*';

                System.out.println();
                for(a=0; a<n; a++){
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    for(b=0; b<n; b++){
                        System.out.print(board[a][b]);
                        for(c=0; c<n; c++)
                            System.out.print("");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                     System.out.println();  

                 System.out.print("Move again: ");
                 move = in.next().charAt(0);     
            break;          
            }

            //Move Down
            case 's':{
                board[i+1][j] = '@';

                i = 0;
                j = 0;
                board[i][j] = '*';

                System.out.println();
                for(a=0; a<n; a++){
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    for(b=0; b<n; b++){
                        System.out.print(board[a][b]);
                        for(c=0; c<n; c++)
                            System.out.print("");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                     System.out.println();  

                 System.out.print("Move again: ");
                 move = in.next().charAt(0);     
            break;          
            }

            default:{ 
                System.out.print("Incorrect move. Press WASD only: ");
                move = in.next().charAt(0);
            }

        }

    System.out.print("Move again.");
    move = in.next().charAt(0);

  }  

  public void display(){

        for(a=0; a<n; a++){
            System.out.print("\t");
                for(b=0; b<n; b++){
                 System.out.print(board[a][b]);
                    for(c=0; c<n; c++)
                       System.out.print("");
                     }
                     System.out.println();
                 }
                 System.out.println();
    }


        public static void main(String[] args){
            Bord brd = new Bord();
        }


}
```

This is my unfinished code. Since this is a dynamic 2D array, how do I change the symbol from `*` to `@` every time the user moves to his/her direction of choice?

Comment: Look at your code. You're using the correct bounds in the loop `a<n` and then you do `board[a][n] = '*';`.

Comment: Should "board[a][n] = '*';" be removed?

Comment: .. well think about the bounds of the array. If you know why you put `<` in `a < n` or `b < n` then you know what's wrong with this line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, and in most languages, Arrays have indexes starting with zero. Thus the first element is at index 0, etc.

In addition, one way you can improve your code is by replacing the first two loops with one nested loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        board[i][j] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this. Thank you very much! I appreciate all the help I can get. :)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the `n`th element in the array is an out-of-bounds access.

The first element is at index `0`, the second at `1`, etc. The last one is at index `n-1`.